# Clear old resources in k8s

Tags: templates, kubernetes

I want to make a command which can clear all old deployments. For example, I have deployments in a namespace

> kubectl -n web get deploy --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp

```
myproject-static-staging-master                  1/1     1            1           54d
myproject-static-staging-task-13373                1/1     1            1           20d
myproject-static-staging-task-13274                1/1     1            1           19d
myproject-static-staging-task-13230                1/1     1            1           19d
myproject-static-staging-task-13323                1/1     1            1           19d
myproject-static-staging-task-13264                1/1     1            1           18d
myproject-static-staging-task-13319                1/1     1            1           13d
myproject-static-staging-task-13470                1/1     1            1           6d20h
myproject-static-staging-task-13179                1/1     1            1           6d20h
myproject-static-staging-task-13453                1/1     1            1           6d4h
myproject-static-staging-moving-to-old           1/1     1            1           6d
myproject-static-staging-moving-test             1/1     1            1           5d20h
```

I want to save only that's (5 newest)

```
myproject-static-staging-task-13470                1/1     1            1           6d20h
myproject-static-staging-task-13179                1/1     1            1           6d20h
myproject-static-staging-task-13453                1/1     1            1           6d4h
myproject-static-staging-moving-to-old           1/1     1            1           6d
myproject-static-staging-moving-test             1/1     1            1           5d20h
```

I tried that command

> kubectl get deployment -n web --template '{{range
> .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
> --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | grep -v master | grep myproject-static-staging | head -n 5 | xargs -r kubectl -n web delete
> deployment

but it is no correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use xargs command like this:

```
command1 | xargs -I{} command2 {}
```

Xargs will replace the output from command1 with the empty {}. For example, if the output of command1 is '1 2 3', then Xargs will invoke commands: 'command2 1', 'command2 2', and 'command2 3'.

So in your case, you can use

```
kubectl get deployment -n web --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | grep -v master | grep myproject-static-staging | tail -r | tail -n +6 | xargs -I{} kubectl -n web delete deployment {}
```

'tail -r' will reverse the order, and 'tail -n +6' will select all rows except the first 5.

Comment: In k8s I have an error(


tail: invalid option -- 'r' Try 'tail --help' for more information.